# Recursive templates arguments: call to implicitly deleted default constructor C++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm making an algebraic data type of either (binary sum type) and both (binary product type) in C++, I would like to implement a composition of the two where it could have either or both; `EitherAll`.

Here is the implementation of `Either`

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class Either
{
public:
  bool left;
  T1 lx;
  T2 rx;
  template <typename T1_, typename T2_>
  friend Either<T1_, T2_> Left(T1_ *x);
  template <typename T1_, typename T2_>
  friend Either<T1_, T2_> Right(T2_ *x);
};

template <typename T1_, typename T2_>
Either<T1_, T2_> Left(T1_ x)
{
  Either<T1_, T2_> e;
  e.left = true;
  e.lx = x;
  return e;
}

template <typename T1_, typename T2_>
Either<T1_, T2_> Right(T2_ x)
{
  Either<T1_, T2_> e;
  e.left = false;
  e.rx = x;
  return e;
}
```

Constructing an object as such works fine

```
Either<int,char> res1 = Left<int,char>(1);
```

I then defined `EitherAll` as an alias

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
using EitherAll = Either<Both<T1, T2>, Either<T1, T2>>;
```

Constructing it causes an error

```
EitherAll<int,char> res = Right<Both<int,char>,Either<int,char>>(Left<int,char>(1));
```

> error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'Either<parser::alg::Both<char, int>, parser::alg::Either<char, int> >'
> Either<T1_, T2_> e;

Adding a default constructor of `Either(){}` will require `lx,rx` to be instantiated rather than delayed and only provided in `Left,Right`. I'm not sure how to make this data structure work.

Heres a [link to godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/a9saxreYP) of the code snippet

Comment: I should probably learn how to use unions right?

Comment: The problem is in `Both`, which does not have a default constructor, so the compiler cannot create a default constructor for `EitherAll` which contains a `Both` member

Answer (score 0):

Your `Either` requires to default-construct both T1/T2.

[`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)/[`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) might help:

```
/*! Disjoint sum type of two parameters */
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class Either
{
public:
  std::variant<T1, T2> data;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
Either<T1, T2> Left(T1 x) { return {std::variant<T1, T2>{std::in_place_index_t<0>{}, x}}; }

template <typename T1, typename T2>
Either<T1, T2> Right(T2 x) { return {std::variant<T1, T2>{std::in_place_index_t<1>{}, x}}; }
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nWaqbEcnh).